# How to set focus across an hierarchy in React

Tags: reactjs

In my React chat-application I have a hierarchy of components like this:

```
ThreadList
    Thread
        Reply
            ReplyMenu
                ReplyButton
                    <button onClick="?" />

        Reply
        Reply
        .
        NewReply
            <input ref={(input) => {this.replyInput = input}}>
```

What I want is that when I press the ReplyButton, focus should be set to the input inside the NewReply component. Can anyone explain to me how to accomplish this in React. I have seen examples where the component setting the focus is an immediate parent of the input, but not in a different part of the hierarchy.

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 1):

You will have to pass on the click event to the parent `Reply` component and then call the focus function from there. So you also need to pass on this function from `Reply` component to each of this child till the `ReplyButton` component

Somthing like

**Reply**

```
focusNewReply() {
     this.replyInput.focus();
}
```

**ReplyMenu**

```
focusNewReply() {
    this.props.focusNewReply();
}
```

**ReplyButton**

```
<button onClick={()=>{this.props.focusNewReply()}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling `focus()` on the input?

```
  render(){
  const _this = this;
  <button onClick={() => _this.replyInput.focus()} />
}
```

Comment: Yes, but since "this" refers to the ReplyButton component and not to the NewReply component, I receive a "Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined."

Comment: @FrankJusnes Ah I see, You can store `this` before chaning down the render components to keep the reference. Same goes for the `ref` in `NewReply`.